# AS3 - playing video within a loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, video, filepath

My file structure is this:
main.swf
/swf/child.swf
/video/testvideo.flv

When I compile the child.swf by itself, it loads and plays video just fine (using netStream.play(../video/testvideo.flv).

However, when I compile the main.swf, which at some point loads child.swf, I get this error when trying to play the video:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
```

How am I supposed to configure the path so that it can be seen when I compile the main swf? I've tried changing the path to just video/testvideo.flv, and I still get the same error.

Comment: If you set the path to "/video/testvideo.flv" and compile child.swf you will get the error, but once you load it into main, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that relative path is based on the parent movie clip, so when you test child.swf, the start path is /swf/ and when you test main.swf, the start path is /.  If you want the video to play for both, you will need to do a little test.  Something like this:

```
var rootPath:String = (root==this) ? "../" : "./";
netStream.play(rootPath + "video/testvideo.flv");
```

That way if you're testing child.swf, `root == this`, so it will use `../video/testvideo.flv` as the path.  If you're testing main.swf, `root != this`, so it will use `./video/testvideo.flv` as the path.