# AS3 standalone video player does not play video files

Tags: actionscript-3, video, mp4, flash-cs6, flvplayback

I am stuck in a problem and can not find a solution. I am on a deadline.

I use Mac and I have created an interactive educational DVD in Flash CS6, AS3 (Flash Player 11.4). I am using autorun method for playing a full screen swf file named (Main.exe). In this project i play different swf files, mp3 audio and mp4 video files externally by usage of XML.

1. Now everything runs smooth while i test my movie in Flash CS6. The problem is that the mp4 videos do not load once i try to play the standalone version of the swf file (Main.swf or Main.exe). I am not sure where the problem lies. Will highly appreciate if anybody can guide me through this strange issue.
2. I have noticed some of the Mp4 video files not loading even on testing in Flash CS6. Some of them load and some of them do not. Although i am getting the path and names correctly through XML. What is going on in this case?? Are the files corrupt?? But all the video files do play if i use some media player.

P.S.: For autorun or (.exe) of course i am testing it on Windows Platform. The DVD is meant to be played on Windows Platform.

Comment: You should use AIR to deploy a desktop application rather than trying to use the platform swf player.  It will give you more access to the system and will have the appropriate security context for loading files from the internet (or local file system).  With regard to some videos working others not, as you say a corrupt video encoding could be an issue.

Comment: @shaunhusain Can you share some good resources for AIR development. I have always used the standalone (.exe) method in the past to success. And this is the first time i am dealing with video content.

Comment: Sorry Majid I'm not aware of any good tutorials for Flash CS6 and AIR here's a short one though http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-publish-an-air-application-in-adobe-flash-c.html Don't take the dummies thing personally just the first site I found googling. I've always used AIR with Flex/FlashBuilder rather than the "regular" Flash IDE.

Answer (score 0):

First off, OS X does not open `.exe` files as those are Windows applications (Macs use `.app`).  However, The `.swf` does work on both platforms (as you noted) since Flash Player is available on both.

Secondly, just because the videos work in a video-player (such as [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)) does not mean they should work in Flash.  Even if the extension is the same between videos (in this case, `.mp4`) it does not mean they should all play equally.  This is because an `.mp4` is nothing more than a container for a video that's [encoded with a codec](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/Video_Codecs.asp).  If the codec is not available in Flash Player, it won't run.

To sanitize your content, consider re-encoding your videos to the same standard format that you can use.  If you have Flash, it comes with [Adobe Media Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/mediaencoder.html), and this should do the job.  Alternatively, try an open-source encoder such as [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

The other issue sounds like a pathing problem, to me.  You'll need to provide code samples to demonstrate what you're doing.

Comment: I test (standalone .swf and .app) while in Mac and (standalone .swf and .exe) while i test on Windows platform. Will certainly give a try to encoding through Adobe Media Encoder.

Comment: The code and file structure is quite complex and not sure what to post here. I have four different categories of lessons as buttons and each category has its media content.

- I am using the main and 3 media Player (audio, video and swf players) swfs on root rest all the the media content such as (swf, audios and videos) are in their respective folders under respective categories folder.

- I have combined all the categories folder under one folder called media which is placed on root.

- I am also using an XML folder on root to hold all the paths for the media content.

Comment: The only question is - why does Flash behave different while compiling and while playing standalone?? i am obviously missing something very basic but not sure what. Thnx for your understanding!! Everybody!!

Comment: As Facundo pointed out, pathing can change based on where your swf is loading from.  If you have a parent SWF which loads child swfs, the directory pathing will be relative to the parent, not the child swfs.  To really debug the issue, you need error reports.  What is the path that you expect it to load, and what is the path that its saying it can't load?  Typically, you'll be using relative paths (ie., "../videos/movie.mp4").  If you're using something like MDM Zinc, the paths are absolute (ie., "file://C/project/videos/movie.mp4"), which you'd then use pointers like `mdm.Application.path`.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer doesn't help, check this question, perhaps it can give you a clue to what is going on: 
[AS3 - playing video within a loaded swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358728/as3-playing-video-within-a-loaded-swf?rq=1)

Comment: I am sure it is not the path issue as i am successfully able to load most of the video content while i compile the swf from Flash. Its only when i play (.swf) file as standalone videos wont load.